# Sporadicall errors with SSL pinning

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, httpclient, bouncycastle

I am trying to implement SSL pinning following this approach:

http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html

The strategy is to put the trusted certificates in a [BKS](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) keystore and extend the [SSLSocketFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) used by the [HTTPClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) so that only certificates included in the keystore are accepted.

It all works fine on multiple test devices (Nexus, Samsung S1, Wildfire, etc.), except on Samsung Galaxy S2 (European version with 2.3.6). Sporadically (one attempt of maybe 3-4) i get one of this error messages:

- error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block
  type is not 01 (SHA-1)
- error:04067084:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:data too large for modulus (SHA-1)

The problem also occurs only if i have multiple keys with the same CNAME entry in the BKS. When i put only one key in the keystore it works fine every time. However in case i want to change the certificate of my backend, to have a smooth transition period, i need the app to be able to accept two keys for the same host.

Any ideas what the cause for the error message might be and how to circumvent it, will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> The strategy is to put the trusted certificates in a BKS keystore
>   and extend the SSLSocketFactory used by the HTTPClient so that only
>   certificates included in the keystore are accepted.

For pinning, you only need to extend `X509TrustManager` and override `checkServerTrusted`.

An example is available at OWASP's [Certificate and Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) (see the Android example). All the examples fetch random bytes from [random.org](http://www.random.org/) and pin the site's certificate to ensure no PKI funny business:

```
public final class PubKeyManager implements X509TrustManager
{
  private static String PUB_KEY = "30820122300d06092a864886f70d0101" +
    "0105000382010f003082010a0282010100b35ea8adaf4cb6db86068a836f3c85" +
    "5a545b1f0cc8afb19e38213bac4d55c3f2f19df6dee82ead67f70a990131b6bc" +
    "ac1a9116acc883862f00593199df19ce027c8eaaae8e3121f7f329219464e657" +
    "2cbf66e8e229eac2992dd795c4f23df0fe72b6ceef457eba0b9029619e0395b8" +
    "609851849dd6214589a2ceba4f7a7dcceb7ab2a6b60c27c69317bd7ab2135f50" +
    "c6317e5dbfb9d1e55936e4109b7b911450c746fe0d5d07165b6b23ada7700b00" +
    "33238c858ad179a82459c4718019c111b4ef7be53e5972e06ca68a112406da38" +
    "cf60d2f4fda4d1cd52f1da9fd6104d91a34455cd7b328b02525320a35253147b" +
    "e0b7a5bc860966dc84f10d723ce7eed5430203010001";

  public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException
  {
    if (chain == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("checkServerTrusted: X509Certificate array is null");
    }

    if (!(chain.length > 0)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("checkServerTrusted: X509Certificate is empty");
    }

    if (!(null != authType && authType.equalsIgnoreCase("RSA"))) {
      throw new CertificateException("checkServerTrusted: AuthType is not RSA");
    }

    // Perform customary SSL/TLS checks
    try {
      TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
      tmf.init((KeyStore) null);

      for (TrustManager trustManager : tmf.getTrustManagers()) {
        ((X509TrustManager) trustManager).checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new CertificateException(e);
    }

    // Hack ahead: BigInteger and toString(). We know a DER encoded Public Key begins
    // with 0x30 (ASN.1 SEQUENCE and CONSTRUCTED), so there is no leading 0x00 to drop.
    RSAPublicKey pubkey = (RSAPublicKey) chain[0].getPublicKey();
    String encoded = new BigInteger(1 /* positive */, pubkey.getEncoded()).toString(16);

    // Pin it!
    final boolean expected = PUB_KEY.equalsIgnoreCase(encoded);
    if (!expected) {
      throw new CertificateException("checkServerTrusted: Expected public key: "
                + PUB_KEY + ", got public key:" + encoded);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i switched to that method a long time ago too. The thing with the BKS store does not work properly and creates an unnecessary overhead...